# Calculate return from selected quarterly data in python pandas from Bloomberg API

Tags: python, pandas, bloomberg

Currently, I'm working with `Bloomberg API`, and do some `web crawler` to Python pandas data frame. I have retrieved the data, and working to do some analysis with them to create some sort of simulation. Let's say, I have this data:

```
                  ABC US Equity
      2011-01-03    243.00
      2011-01-04    243.58
      2011-01-05    243.45
      2011-01-06    244.28
      2011-01-07    244.13
      2011-01-10    244.32
      2011-01-11    245.83
      2011-01-12    246.31
      2011-01-13    247.05
      2011-01-14    247.39
      2011-01-17    249.24
      2011-01-18    248.93
      2011-01-19    248.68
      2011-01-20    248.30
      2011-01-21    249.81
               ...  
      2011-04-01    437.32
               ...
      2011-07-01    438.40
               ...
      2011-10-03    438.79
               ... 
      2012-01-03    438.79
```

**Objective**

I would like to add new column that calculates return based on this criteria:

1. It takes value from quarterly interval data, in this case from *2011-04-01*, *2011-07-01*, *2011-10-03* and *2011-01-03*
2. Average them and divide them with data from *2011-01-03* and put the result in the new column at *2012-01-03* row
3. It is applicable for the the next row as well

**Expectation**

```
                 ABC US Equity   Return
      2011-01-03    243.00      #The result should be (average(437.32+438.40+438.79+439.81)/243.00)-1
      2011-01-04    243.58       and so on, same calculation on the next row
      2011-01-05    243.45       ... 
      2011-01-06    244.28       ...
      2011-01-07    244.13       ... 
      2011-01-10    244.32
      2011-01-11    245.83
      2011-01-12    246.31
      2011-01-13    247.05
      2011-01-14    247.39
      2011-01-17    249.24
      2011-01-18    248.93
      2011-01-19    248.68
      2011-01-20    248.30
      2011-01-21    249.81
               ...  
      2011-04-01    437.32
               ...
      2011-07-01    438.40
               ...
      2011-10-03    438.79
               ... 
      2012-01-03    439.81
```

So far, I have attempted to calculate only the mean, but the result itself is still far from my expectation

```
df['Return'] = [
    df2.loc[
        edt - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=4):edt,
        'ABC US Equity'].mean() 
        for edt in df.index
```

This code instead produces "rolling" mean, not something what I expect.

Does anybody know how to crack this problem?, I have spent days to figure this out. I'm new to Python, apologies if it's basic problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the first set of quarters:

```
quarters = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(2011,4,1), periods=4, freq='BQS')
```

To make them rolling forward 1-day, you can use a list comprehension:

```
rolling_quarters = [quarters + pd.Timedelta(days=i) for i in range(len(df))]
```

Your comparison values are then:

```
comp_values = [df.reindex(q).values.mean() for q in rolling_quarters]
```

Your results would be:

```
comp_values/df['ABC US Equity']-1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.date_range` to set the comparison quarters. You just choose the start date, select how many periods you want, and by setting `freq='BQS'`, you get business quarter starts:

```
quarters = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(2011,4,1), periods=4, freq='BQS')
```

You can then set your result column to:

```
(df.loc[df['date_column'].isin(quarters), ['ABC US Equity']]
   .apply(lambda x: x.mean()/df['ABC US Equity']-1))
```

EDIT: If your date column is the index, you can do:

```
df.reindex(quarters).apply(lambda x: x.mean()/df['ABC US Equity']-1)
```

Make sure your index is a datetimeindex. If it isn't you can do:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Note: Your sample includes 2 values with the date 2011-01-03. If the last value is a mistake, you may want to start your quarters at 2011-04-01, which will give you 2012-01-02 as your last quarter date. If they're both valid but you want to exclude the first in the average, you will need to add `.iloc[1:]` to the first line above.

Comment: Hi @seanswe , yest it's a mistake, it's supposed to be 2012-01-03, which is 4 quarters from the 2011-01-01. Does this make significant change to the code? Thanks

Comment: Also, the date column in my data is an index, I guess. Because, I tried to run your code, but it's not working. Need your advice. Thanks

Comment: I thought it might be the index--please see edit. Not a big change. I think the last quarter is 2012-01-02.

Comment: Hi Sean, I just realized, the next row still using the same input from 2011-04-01, 2011-07-01, 2011-10-03, 2012-01-02 for the mean calculation. I was thinking that the next row (2011-01-04) should adjust by +1 day as well for all the series of date from earlier row, I'm trying to figure it out on my own, but kinda stuck, any clue?